# How to use scikit-learn linear regression without using split?

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

I got 2 CSV named train.csv and test.csv.

Both files have the same structure, and I want to use train.csv as train data and test.csv as test data.

The thing is, I can't find anywhere how to use scikit-learn linear regression without using split, every tutorial/documentation I find uses the function train_test_split(), but if I understand correctly it's used to split one file (let's say data.csv) as both train and test data.

Is it even possible? If no, what alternative can I use?

Comment: Just don't use the split function. Read your `train.csv` as the train dataset and your `test.csv` as your test dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have separate `train`,  `test` data,

define `X_train` and `y_train`

- `X_train` is the features excluding the target variable

```py
# Sudo Code
X_train = train.drop(target, axis=1)
```

- `y_train` is the target variable

```
# Sudo Code
y_train = train[target]
```

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
```